# Do I need to create my own init for a class? If not, in what situations is neccessary to write own init?

Tags: objective-c, initialization

So if I have a class I can miss writing explicit init. But in what situation it can be neccessary to write "own" init?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need the class to configure instance variables to a known state as soon as the instance is initialized.

This initial state can be possibly influenced by the caller, with `init` methods like `initWithSomething:` or sometimes not.

If you have a class where it doesn't matter about the initial state of instance variables then you don't need to write your own `init` method.

You might also want to set-up notifications and other binding mechanisms to related objects, which might need to be done in the `init` method, unless there are some entry point (i.e. method) that is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to inizialize important values for your class you'll want to create your own init.

It is never neccessary in your 'own' class. It is a matter of design.

This might be interesting for you:
[Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

Create your init method is not mandatory, but it's the recommend way to initialise your variables to he default value.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you write your own init to initialize state for your class, as it is better to be explicit about what values instance variables hold to avoid faulty assumptions.

Example:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {

    // no ivars

}

@end

@implementation ClassA

// no init as there is no state for you to initialize

- (void)methodA {

}

//...

@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject {

    // ivars here
    BOOL isDateSet;
    NSDate *date;

}

@end

@implementation ClassB

// init here because there are instance variables present in ClassB
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        isDateSet = NO;
        date = [NSDate distantPast];
    }
}

- (void)methodB {

}

//...

@end
```